# Should the hazelcast domain in the identity server be the same as the API manager domain?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm running a clustered environment with an API manager and two worker nodes, and key manager identity server as two nodes. My question regards the axis2.xml in the identity server. For the API Manager documentation it says change the domain to **wso2.am.domain**.

```
<parameter name="domain">wso2.am.domain</parameter>
```

In the identity server cluster documentation it doesn't say anything about this. Should it be part of the API Manager domain, or since it is its own application should the nodes be on **wso2.is.domain** I'm just not sure what it even affects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the following deployment.

1. Single APIM node - works as Publisher,Store and Gateway Manager
2. Two gateway worker nodes
3. Two Key Manager nodes - This is two identity server nodes.

For this kind of a deployment you can have a domain called wso2.am.domain for Single APIM node and two gateway worker nodes. For identity server nodes you can have any other name such as wso2.is.domain.

Basically, publisher and store nodes should belong to the same domain. In your case both are running on a single node. Also, gateway manager and gateway workers should have a separate domain. As you are running gateway manager in single APIM node, that domain name should be same as two gateway worker nodes. And Key manager nodes should have a separate domain as well. So in your case, you can have any name apart from wso2.am.domain for the identity server nodes.